# How can I access CakePHP log files on Heroku?

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku

I've deployed a CakePHP application to Heroku. CakePHP writes its logs in `APP_ROOT/app/tmp/logs/error.log` and `APP_ROOT/app/tmp/logs/debug.log` by default but since there's no way to get a shell to a running Heroku web dyno, I can't see the content of those files.

As I understand it, the `heroku logs` command returns everything which has been dumped to `STDERR` and `STDOUT`. If I'm right about that, is there a way to force CakePHP to send its logs to `STDOUT`?

[The Heroku PHP Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) tails the Apache and PHP log files as a background process as part of the dyno setup. See below.

```
cat >>boot.sh <<EOF
for var in \`env|cut -f1 -d=\`; do
  echo "PassEnv \$var" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf;
done
touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/app/www
echo "Launching apache"
exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
EOF
```

In a fork of that build pack, I added in my own lines in the appropriate positions, then configured my app to use my custom build pack.

```
touch /app/www/tmp/logs/error.log
tail -F /app/www/app/tmp/logs/error.log &
```

But this didn't work. In fact, setting aside CakePHP specifics, I don't see any PHP or Apache log contents in the `heroku logs` either.

Comment: You can use [DatabaseLog](https://github.com/dereuromark/CakePHP-DatabaseLog) to log to the database, either the same (default) or some other. The advantage is that they are not lost on redeploy, shared between multiple apps if applicable, and can easier be searched this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might work. Make sure you're using CakePHP 2.3.9.

```
App::uses('ConsoleOutput', 'Console');

CakeLog::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
    'stream' => new ConsoleOutput('php://stdout')
));

CakeLog::config('stdout', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info'),
    'stream' => new ConsoleOutput('php://stdout')
));

CakeLog::config('stderr', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
    'types' => array('emergency', 'alert', 'critical', 'error', 'warning', 'debug'),
    'stream' =>  new ConsoleOutput('php://stderr')
));


CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'format' => 'debug %s: %s',
    'stream' => new ConsoleOutput('php://stdout')
));

CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'format' => 'error %s: %s',
    'stream' =>  new ConsoleOutput('php://stderr')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging#cakephp

In your application configuration, instruct CakePHP to use the ConsoleLog engine for your logger setups:

```
CakeLog::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'ConsoleLog',
));
```

You can then use the regular logging methods.

```
CakeLog::warning("Hello, this is a test message!");
```

Refer to the Logging section of the CakePHP manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of CakePHP (>= 3.6.0), the `config/app.php` file comes pre-configured to use an environment variable override for the stock `debug` and `error` logs. These vars [should contain a DSN-style string](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) defining the same attributes you would normally place in your `config/app.php` file.

In the Heroku dashboard under **Settings** (or via the `heroku` cli tool), you can add the following ENV vars:

```
LOG_DEBUG_URL = file:///?className=Cake%5CLog%5CEngine%5CConsoleLog&levels[]=notice&levels[]=info&levels[]=debug
LOG_ERROR_URL = file:///?className=Cake%5CLog%5CEngine%5CConsoleLog&levels[]=warning&levels[]=error&levels[]=critical&levels[]=alert&levels[]=emergency
```

The above two lines replicate the stock CakePHP logging, but redirect all output to the console instead of files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\ConsoleLog'`

```
/**
 * Configures logging options
 */
'Log' => [
    'debug' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\ConsoleLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'debug',
        'levels' => ['notice', 'info', 'debug'],
        'url' => env('LOG_DEBUG_URL', null),
    ],
    'error' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\ConsoleLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'error',
        'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
        'url' => env('LOG_ERROR_URL', null),
    ],
],
```