# How to capture production CakePHP 3 error logs on Heroku

Tags: php, cakephp, logging, heroku

My CakePHP 3.x app is running on Heroku. When in production mode (`debug => false`) none of the errors show up in the Heroku logs. I suspect that CakePHP is trying to write them to it's own `logs/error.log` but I don't think there's a way to access that in the Heroku environment. I think I need to configure CakePHP to send errors to STDOUT... then Heroku will "see" them. How do I do that in CakePHP v3.x?

Here's the relevant section of my config file:

```
'Error' => [
    'errorLevel' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer',
    'skipLog' => [],
    'log' => true,
    'trace' => true,
],
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717420/how-can-i-access-cakephp-log-files-on-heroku) is exactly the same as mine, but for CakePHP 2.x.

[This Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging#cakephp) is also for CakePHP 2.x.

Here is the [CakePHP documentation on logging](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#error-and-exception-logging) which is vague on this matter.

I tried adding...

```
use Cake\Log\Log;

Log::config('default', [
    'engine' => 'Syslog'
]);
```

...to my config file but it didn't work.

Comment: `Syslog != Console`. I have no Heroku experience, but if you want to log to `php://stderr` (which is what `ConsoleLog` in 2.x does), then you need to use the `Console` engine.

Comment: @ndm if I replace `Syslog` with `Console` is my approach otherwise correct?

Comment: I would think so (given that by "_config file_" you are not referring to  `config/app.php`).

Comment: @ndm we'll sort of. We use one main app.config file and turn override it selectively for specific environments. So my snippet is in the override for production. The docs say to use bootstrap but I don't want this to apply to all environments. Does that make sense?

Comment: Generally, yes. Though I wouldn't use programming logic in a configuration file, that feels kinda odd, and makes interchanging configuration file formats a little cumbersome. Personally I'm using environment specific bootraps that merge in additional configuration if necessary.

Comment: @ndm good point. We made a point to NOT do that elsewhere... I didn't think about environment-specific bootstraps... That's definitely better

Comment: @ndm swapped out `Syslog` for `Console` but I'm still not seeing any errors in the logs. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry, as I said, I have no Heroku experience, all I can say is that the `Console` engine logs to `php://stderr` just like in 2.x.

Comment: @ndm Should the `Console` engine be equivalent to where vanilla PHP would send it's errors? For example, if I just push a single test.php file to Heroku with something like `error_log('foo bar')` Heroku will "see" that. Is `Console` analogous to that?

Comment: Woah woah woah hold the presses... looks like Heroku IS seeing the errors but the logging-addon (Logentries) isn't! Rrrr. @ndm This means your suggestion was right... care to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where we ended up:

```
# Configure all logs for Heroku.
foreach (array_keys(Configure::read('Log')) as $log) {
    Configure::write("Log.$log.className", 'Console');
}
```

This applies the solution from emersonthis to every configured log. We place this in our configuration override files for Heroku environments. I'm not sure about the `engine` vs. `className` difference between our examples. The current CakePHP 3 cookbook [uses className](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-configuration) for its own examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is a placeholder answer (while the info is still fresh) in my mind until NDM submits one...

```
To log errors to the console, add...

Log::config('default', [
    'engine' => 'Console'
]);
```

...to bootstrap.php

This results in PHP errors showing up when you run `heroku logs`. The mistake I made was trusting the Heroku addon Logentries, which is a GUI tool for viewing logs. Even with the above in place, Logentries still isn't showing any PHP errors, but that's a different issue.

Possibly relevant:

At the bottom of [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging#adding-logging-for-legacy-applications) it shows you how to connect applications that log to their own files (like CakePHP) with Heroku's black magic output... it didn't work for me, but your milage may vary.